# dmesg log to file, and check number of lines

Tags: bash, dmesg

i trying to drop last new lines(if exists) of dmesg to a file. I want to echo it if there is new lines that file. There isn't much of it, but i have something like this:

```
flog=$DIR/dmlog
dm=$(dmesg > $flog)
lines=$(wc -l $flog) <--- for example there is 60 lines
```

I need to check if number of lines is greater than previouse one (60).

Comment: If you just want to check whether a file is growing, run `tail -f` and have it run a command as soon as there is any output.

Comment: Yes, I want to compare it. For example: I will do "dmesg > $flog" every 10minutes, and when number lines in 'wc -l' is greater than previous, then I want to check $flog (dmlog)

Comment: Compare the file by the number of lines of this file.